# Launch Swagger UI with default values specified in the URL

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

I would like to craft a URL to the Swagger UI that opens up a particular API/method and fills in parameter values that I specify on the URL.  Is this possible?  For example:

`https://myserver.com/swagger/ui/index#!/MyApi/MyMethod?Param1=Foo&Parm2=Bar`

This would allow the user to just fill in any remaining parameters and click Try It Now!

Note: I'm not asking for static default values, I would like a dynamic solution that this feature would provide.

I am using Swashbuckle 5.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom Js to populate fields dynamically from url

```cs
.UseSwaggerUI(o =>
{
   o.HeadContent += "<script> /* some code goes here */ </script>";

   o.EnableTryItOutByDefault();
})
```

see also `o.Interceptors.RequestInterceptorFunction`

Comment: I have a .NET Framework app, not Core and am using
`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableSwaggerUi()` which doesn't have a `HeadContent()`. `InjectJavaScript` will probably do the same thing.  Will look into that.  Thanks.